# What is the significance of Tomcat in Jenkins installation? / What is the use of Tomcat in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, devops

I installed Jenkins directly in Ubuntu. In such cases we not required Tomcat? Or Jenkins Tomcat combination having any specific advantage/use cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins requires a Servlet Container to run. Therefore you can either:

- run the WAR file as a standalone application, in which case an integrated Jetty server is spawn (cf. [Installation guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/)),
- deploy the WAR file on an external servlet container like Tomcat.

There is no major difference between the two methods. However, if you run a Tomcat instance anyway, it is easier to have everything in the same servlet container.

Comment: I installed `openjdk-8-jre` then installed `jenkins` using `apt-get install jenkins` . So in this method also there is a `Servlet Container ` is getting created ?

Comment: Yes, the Hybrid JAR/WAR file `/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war` contains a copy of [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), which is used when you use file as a normal JAR: `java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war`.